# how do i plot coordinates from a list so that they line up with a map of the world?

Tags: python, pandas, mapping

I'm doing a school project where we chose a dataset and analyze/present it using python. I chose one about vulcanic eruptions  and as part of my project i want to plot the all the eruptions on a map along with the tectonic plate boundaries to show how they correlate. My current approach has been to find a list of the coordinates that make up the plate boundaries and trying to plot them on a map using the method shown [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/easy-steps-to-plot-geographic-data-on-a-map-python-11217859a2db), but it doesn't seem to work very well with the amount of coordinates I have and how zoomed out my map is compared to the one in the tutorial. my coordinates don't line up with my map, and they seem to be slightly "stretched" in the y direction

[image: this is the image i used] and [this](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/cwthompson/tectonic-plate-boundaries) is where my .csv file comes from

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd



long = []
lat = []


dtf = open("tp.csv", "r")
lines = dtf.readlines()

for row in lines[1:]:
    vals = row.strip().split(",")
    long.append(vals[2])
    lat.append(vals[1])




while("" in long):
    long.remove("")

while("" in lat):
    lat.remove("")


for i in range(0, len(long)):
    long[i]=float(long[i])

for i in range(0, len(lat)):
    lat[i]=float(lat[i])





longvu = []
latvu = []

dtf = open("vulkanutbrudd kordinater.csv")
lines = dtf.readlines()

for row in lines[0:]:
    vals = row.strip().split(";")
    longvu.append(vals[1])
    latvu.append(vals[0])




while("" in longvu):
    long.remove("")

while("" in latvu):
   lat.remove("")


for i in range(0, len(longvu)):
    longvu[i]=float(longvu[i])

for i in range(0, len(latvu)):
    latvu[i]=float(latvu[i])

long.insert(0,-180)
long.insert(1,180)
lat.insert(0,-90)
lat.insert(1,90 )



BBox = [min(long), max(long), min(lat), max(lat)]


kart = plt.imread("map.png")


fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (8,7))
ax.scatter(long, lat, zorder=1, alpha= 0.2, c='b', s=1)
ax.set_xlim(BBox[0],BBox[1])
ax.set_ylim(BBox[2],BBox[3])
ax.set_xlim(-180.00, 180.00)
ax.set_ylim(-90.00,90.00)

ax.imshow(kart,zorder=0, extent = BBox, aspect= 'auto')

plt.show()

dtf.close()
```

above is the code i have the code i've written thus far. "vulkanutbrudd" is vulcanic eruption and longvu and latvu is the cordinates for the vulcanic eruptions that i havent gotten to use yet. im open to using tools, other than python as well

Answer (score 0):

if you're still searching for a python-package... have a look at [EOmaps](https://github.com/raphaelquast/EOmaps)!

You can plot datapoints like this:

```
import numpy as np
from eomaps import Maps

vals, long, lat = (np.random.randint(-90, 90, 100) for i in range(3))

m = Maps()
m.add_feature.preset.coastline()
m.add_feature.preset.ocean()

m.set_data(vals, long, lat, crs=4326)

m.set_shape.ellipses(radius=2) # for up to ~200 000 points you can use
# m.set_shape.shade_points()   # for more datapoints, use shading...

m.plot_map()

m.cb.pick.attach.annotate()
```